# How to enable Tablet/Touch Mode in Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, touchscreen, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

When running Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with a touchscreen the touch interaction seems to be stuck in a desktop mode (a mouse cursor is displayed, multi-line textboxes can't be swiped to reveal more content, etc.) How can I force the tablet/touch mode to be enabled?

I've tried adding the TabletMode and SignInMode registry entries to the DefaultAccount registry location:

```
New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2702878673-795188819-444038987-503\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" -Name "ImmersiveShell"
New-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2702878673-795188819-444038987-503\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell" -Name "TabletMode" -Value "0x00000001" -PropertyType "DWord"
New-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2702878673-795188819-444038987-503\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell" -Name "SignInMode" -Value "0x00000000" -PropertyType "DWord"
```

I've tried checking `UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode` in my UWP app and it is `Touch` as expected.

What am I missing? If I instead run the same UWP app in the Visual Studio Simulator and choose the Basic Touch input option then the UWP app interactions work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/wcd/wcd-tabletmode), at the moment TabletMode does not apply to Windows IoT Core.Please use Feedback Hub app to report this requirement.The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run in to while using Windows and send suggestions to help us improve your Windows experience.

Comment: I'm not sure if TabletMode is the right setting to make the UWP application act as if it were run with the simulator and Basic Touch input option. Is there some other detection of a touch screen which makes UWP apps accept swipes, etc. like in the simulator?

Comment: Also, `Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities()` reports `TouchPresent=1` and `Contacts=10`.